# 'object HTMLUListElement' get printed alongside the content im trying to generate on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this is my html

```
<ul class="list-group mt-sm-3" id="listaLibri" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: auto; max-height:800px">

</ul>
```

this is my Js

```
        reqI.done(function(rsp)
        {
            rspS = JSON.parse(rsp)
            rspA = Object.values(rspS)
            var length = rspA.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                if (rspA[i].hasOwnProperty('volumeInfo')) 
                {
                    if (rspA[i]['volumeInfo'].hasOwnProperty('title')) 
                    {
                        var title = rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['title'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var title = "nessun titolo"
                    }

                    var isbn10 = 'ND';
                    var isbn13 = 'ND';
                    if (rspA[i]['volumeInfo'].hasOwnProperty('industryIdentifiers'))
                    {
                        for (let j = 0; j < rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'].length; j++) 
                        {
                            if(rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][j].hasOwnProperty('identifier'))
                            {
                                if(rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][j]['type'] == 'ISBN_10')
                                    isbn10 = rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][j]['identifier'];
                                else if (rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][j]['type'] == 'ISBN_13')
                                    isbn13 = rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][j]['identifier'];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (rspA[i]['volumeInfo'].hasOwnProperty('imageLinks'))
                    {
                        var img = rspA[i]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']["smallThumbnail"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var img = "./propic/default.png"
                    }

                    listaLibri += '<li class="list-group-item">' 
                                + '<div class="float-left mr-sm-2"><img src="'+ img +'" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: auto; height: auto; max-width: 70px; min-width: 70px; max-height: 100px; min-height: 100px;"></div>'
                                + '<span class = "lead">' + title + '</span><br>'
                                + '<span class = "lead text-muted">ISBN10: ' + isbn10 + '</span><br>'     
                                + '<span class = "lead text-muted">ISBN13: ' + isbn13 + '</span>'  
                                + '<span class = "float-right"><button class = "btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>'
                                + '</li>';       
                }
                $('#listaLibri').html(listaLibri);  
            }
        });
    });      
  
$('#listaLibri').html(listaLibri);
```

and when i try to load the content i generate (all the vars are generated before from an ajax request) i always get "[object HTMLUListElement]" and then the contents, so *it works* but obv i can't leave that "[object HTMLUListElement]" wrote on the page, any idea in how to remove it?[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnaxA.png)

Comment: The part of the code you've shown is not what's generating that string. Most likely it's coming from something you append to `listaLibri` before the concatenation above. Could you show more of the relevant code please.

Comment: [HTMLUListElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUListElement).   `[object HTMLUListElement]` will be presented when you try to "toString()" a `ul` DOM object.  Objects are coerced to strings when concatenated with other strings.  As it appears *before* your other content (and not, say, instead of `title`) then it will be whatever you've added to `listaLibri` just before your code with `listaLibri +=` - *maybe* change `listaLibri +=` to `listaLibri =`

Comment: listaLibri is probably a global variable via `id` attribute, so rather `listaLibriContent = ...`  (note `=`, not `+=`), then `$('#listaLibri').html(listaLibriContent )`;

Comment: @freedomn-m yes it was that! after that i had to change .html to .append and it works!

Comment: @freedomn-m if you want to answer with that comment so i can mark the question as solved it would be nice for future noobs like me, have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[object HTMLUListElement]` will be presented when you try to "toString()" a ul DOM object.

Objects are coerced to strings when concatenated with other strings.

---

In this case `listaLibriContent` is being used as a global variable and is set prior to the code in question.

You could

- reset it before use `listaLibriContent = ""` (outside the `for` loop)
- set it rather than append: change `+=` to `=`
- declare the variable as required `var listaLibriContent;` (inside the `for` loop) to supersed the global variable

You should always declare variables as you need them, in the inner-most scope that it's needed.  (javascript has traditionally messed with this as `var` is defined at the function level, regardless of whether it appears in an inner scope).

There may also need to be other changes, in this case:

```
for (..) {
    if (..) {
        let listaLibriContent = "..."
        $('#listaLibri').append(listaLibri);  
    }
}
```

or

```
let listaLibriContent = "";
for (..) {
    if (..) {
        listaLibriContent += "...";
    }
}
$('#listaLibri').html(listaLibri);
```

In the second case, the html is all built first and then appended in a single step.  Changing DOM elements can be time-expensive - when there's a lot of HTML to update, it's generally quicker to have a single .append / .html (especially when `<table>`s are involved (not the case here)).  If there's a handful, there's no difference, so stick with cleanest (probably first case above).